# While calling SOAP web service getting error AxisFault faultCode: 90010001

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client, webservice-client

I have created SOAP web service client from WSDL/WSDL URL, and trying to call service.
I am getting this error (error Trace)

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: 90010001
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: Mandatory field is not set in EAI_SOAPINPUT; Element -&gt; Environment.eaiCommon.BTID, Environment.eaiCommon.Header.ChannelID, Environment.eaiCommon.Header.RequestUUID, Environment.eaiCommon.Header.ServiceRequestId, Environment.eaiCommon.Header.ServiceRequestVersion
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:Mandatory field is not set in EAI_SOAPINPUT; Element -&gt; Environment.eaiCommon.BTID, Environment.eaiCommon.Header.ChannelID, Environment.eaiCommon.Header.RequestUUID, Environment.eaiCommon.Header.ServiceRequestId, Environment.eaiCommon.Header.ServiceRequestVersion
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at uk.co.mclsoftware.www.HunterII.WebServices.MatchingSoapStub.match(MatchingSoapStub.java:116)
    at uk.co.mclsoftware.www.HunterII.WebServices.MatchingSoapProxy.match(MatchingSoapProxy.java:50)
    at com.huntermatching.test.TestClient.main(TestClient.java:14)
```

it is asking me for mandatory fields.
what is this error?

message portion from wsdl:

```
<wsdl:message name="subHeader">
        <wsdl:part element="xsd:subHeader" name="subHeader" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="MatchSoapIn">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:Match" name="parameters" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="MatchSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:MatchResponse" name="parameters" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="MatchingSoap">
        <wsdl:operation name="Match">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:MatchSoapIn" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:MatchSoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
```

My Client java class is

```
public class TestMatchClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            MatchingSoapProxy matchObj = new MatchingSoapProxy();

            String  controlXml="TestXmlString",batchXml="TestBatchXmlString",uName ="MyUserName",pass = "MyPass";

            matchObj.match(controlXml, batchXml, uName, pass);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you filling the request object entirely ? It seems a server generated fault due to a wrong invocation. Please add calling code and at least the message portion of WSDL in order to dig a bit deeper in this.

Comment: Hi @BigMike , i have added message tag from wsdl, Thanks for reply

Comment: I might be wrong, but we didnt prepare request header object manually it is generated from stub classes. If I should prepare request with required parameter then please tell me how to prepare request object form my service.

Comment: Usually you have to set fields on the generated Request Object. 
The generated stub simply builds up the SOAP envelope, not the inner message. Once you have the request object, you should check it for setter and populate the fields accordingly. Tip: in eclipse, after allocating the request object, inspect all the set... methods. You should see all the setter need to populate a tns:Match type.

Comment: @BigMike , i added my client code, I am calling my match service using proxy class object and i didnt find another setter method for that. how should i call my service method, kindly provide any link or piece of code.

Comment: Seems that the service requires some mandatory elements (BTID, ChannelID, RequestUUID, ServiceRequestId and ServiceRequestVersion), probably in the SOAP header. Check this for how to manipulate SOAP header with Axis http://www.nsftools.com/stubby/SOAPHeaders.htm